# Can't pass variable in block directive from transactional email template

Tags: magento, email, block, transactional-email

I've loaded New Order transactional email to insert a custom block. I inserted it under the order items table layout handle call, and try to pass it `$order` variable.

```
{{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}}
...
{{block type="mymodule/sales_order_email_description" order=$order}}
```

In Mymodule_Block_Sales_Order_Email_Description class I wrote:

```
protected function _construct() {        
    $this->setTemplate('email/order/description.phtml');
}
```

And finally in description.phtml I try to access order:

```
$order = $this->getOrder();
...
$order->getId()
```

At this point, exception rise:
`Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on a non-object ... ...`

I followed several tutorials, like this [magento email templates](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-advanced-transactional-email-templates) but I'm still stuck with this fatal error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look;

You can define the block with a template, the construct isn't needed any more.
`{{block type="mymodule/sales_order_email_description" template="email/order/description.phtml" order=$order}}`

Indeed you could get the parameter values with `$this->getOrder()`. But `$order->getId()` may not work, `$order->getEntityId()`.
Maybe you could try a var_dump to see if there is any order data.

Answer (score -1):

Try this in your .phtml file:

```
$order = $this->getData('order');
```

As described here: http://www.webspeaks.in/2011/06/customize-new-order-email-template-in-magento.html